# Who do I find which cells were affected in an edit

Tags: google-apps-script

Recently started with Google Apps Scripts.

I'm trying to find a way to identify which cells were edited in an edit operations. The `onChange` event only notifies about the type of the edit, but not the region.

Is there an API in place to identify this?

Comment: replace "Recently started with Google Apps Scripts." with **"Recently started reading documentation on Google Apps Scripts".**

Comment: `Spreadsheet edit event` can be helpful. Read the following section of the documentation: [Understanding Events](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_events)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: you cant. While onChange/onEdit give you some info sometimes, its not always correct as there might be more than one cell/row changing. For example a paste into a range with more than one row it will  not tell you about the range changing. Same with deleting multiple rows and other situations.